# Accumulating values of array elements and reiterate for entire array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, matrix

I have a matrix `A` of size 3780x30974. This matrix consists of `0` and `1`. I would like to calculate the sum of fixed windows of length `21` (180 blocks). This should be reiterated, so that the output returns a vector of size 180x30974.

If the first 21 values in a column have a value of 1, the output should return 21. However, if the following 21 values have a value of 1 again, it should return 21 as well. In my code, it accumulates the values, so I obtain 42.

I have `t=3780`, `p=180`, `w=21`;

```
B = movsum(A,w); % the sum of a moving window with width w
```

This question is somehow related to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135644/matlab-calculating-sum-of-array-elements-and-reiterate-for-entire-array) previously asked, yet with a different problem setting. I thought about a loop to say "perform from `t=1:p`", yet it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
result = permute(sum(reshape(A, w, [], size(A,2)), 1), [2 3 1]);
```

---

This works as follows: reshape `A` into a 3D array of size `21`×`180`×`30974`:

```
reshape(A, w, [], size(A,2)), 1)
```

then sum along the first dimension

```
sum(..., 1)
```

and finally remove the first (singleton) dimension by permuting it to the end:

```
permute(..., [2 3 1])
```

Note that Matlab arrays have an [infinite number of trailing singleton dimensions](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html), so moving a singleton dimension to the end is the same as removing it.

Comment: Solution works perfectly well. To understand your code a little bit better, could you please tell me what part of your explantion does the [2 3 1] play?

Comment: @Joe It permutes the first (singleton) dimension to the end, which is the same as removing it. I added an explanation